# How do I get appdata/local/<MyProgramFolder>/ path in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I used fstream and used getenv to get the path of appdata. I used the following codes but it output on appdata/roaming/

```
QString appdata = getenv("appdata");
appdata += "\\DoDLog.log";
fstream stud;
stud.open(appdata.toStdString().c_str(), ios::app);
```

What I want to happen is the path of appdata/local//DoDLog.log

MyProgram is the c++ program that i've been running. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SHGetSpecialFolderLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderlocation)

This is a C solution, it shouldn't be hard to adapt it to C++, `QString`, `std::string` or whatever.

```
#include <shlobj.h>
...
HRESULT GetFolderLocation (int csidl, char* buffer)
{
  LPITEMIDLIST pidl = 0;      
  HRESULT result = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL, csidl, &pidl);      
  *buffer = 0 ;

  if (result == 0)
  {
      SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, buffer);
      CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
  }

  return result;
}

...
char str[_MAX_PATH];
GetFolderLocation(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, str);
// now str contains "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local"
...
```

Comment: think better in this case use `SHGetFolderPath` or, if not support xp, `SHGetKnownFolderPath`

Comment: @RbMm you're probably right. I copy/pasted this code from a very old but still active project. If you post your own answer you'll have my upvote.